# How to speed up PostgreSQL aggregate select with sub queries and case statements

Tags: postgresql

**Background**: I have a table containing financial transaction records.  The table has several tens of millions of rows for tens of thousands of users.  I need to fetch the sum of the transactions for showing balances and other aspects of the site.

My current query can get extremely slow and often times out.  I have tried optimizing the query but can't seem to get it to run efficiently.

**Environment**: My application is running on Heroku using a Postgres Standard-2 plan (8GB ram, 400 max connections, 256GB allowed storage).  My max connections at any given time is about 20 and my current DB size is 35GB.  According to statistics, this query runs on average about 1,000ms and is used very frequently which has a big impact on site performance.

For the database, the index cache hit rate is 99% and the table cache hit rate is 97%.  Autovacuum runs about every other day based on the current thresholds.

Here's my current transactions table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
id bigint DEFAULT nextval('transactions_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
user_id integer NOT NULL,
date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
amount numeric(15,2) NOT NULL,
transaction_type integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
account_id integer DEFAULT 0,
reconciled integer DEFAULT 0,
parent integer DEFAULT 0,
ccparent integer DEFAULT 0,
created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX transactions_user_id_key ON transactions USING btree (user_id);
CREATE INDEX transactions_user_date_idx ON transactions (user_id, date);
CREATE INDEX transactions_user_ccparent_idx ON transactions (user_id, ccparent) WHERE ccparent >0;
```

And here's my current query:

```
SELECT account_id,
 sum(deposit) - sum(withdrawal) AS balance,
 sum(r_deposit)-sum(r_withdrawal) AS r_balance,
 sum(deposit) AS o_deposit,
 sum(withdrawal) AS o_withdrawal,
 sum(r_deposit) AS r_deposit,
 sum(r_withdrawal) AS r_withdrawal
FROM 
(SELECT t.account_id,
    CASE
        WHEN transaction_type > 0 THEN sum(amount)
        ELSE 0
    END AS deposit,
    CASE
        WHEN transaction_type = 0 THEN sum(amount)
        ELSE 0
    END AS withdrawal,
    CASE
        WHEN transaction_type > 0 AND reconciled=0 THEN sum(amount)
        ELSE 0
    END AS r_deposit,
    CASE
        WHEN transaction_type = 0 AND reconciled=0 THEN sum(amount)
        ELSE 0
    END AS r_withdrawal
FROM transactions AS t
WHERE user_id = $1 AND parent=0 AND ccparent=0
GROUP BY  transaction_type, account_id, reconciled ) AS t0
GROUP BY  account_id;
```

The query has several parts.  I have to get the following for each account the user has:

1) the overall account balance

2) the balance for all reconciled transactions

3) separately, the sum of all deposits, withdrawals, reconciled deposits and reconciled withdrawals.

Here's one query plan when I run `explain analyze` on the query:

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 HashAggregate  (cost=13179.85..13180.14 rows=36 width=132) (actual time=1326.200..1326.204 rows=6 loops=1)
   Group Key: t.account_id
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=13179.29..13179.58 rows=36 width=18) (actual time=1326.163..1326.171 rows=16 loops=1)
         Group Key: t.transaction_type, t.account_id, t.reconciled
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on transactions t  (cost=73.96..13132.07 rows=13491 width=18) (actual time=17.410..1317.863 rows=12310 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: (user_id = 1)
               Filter: ((parent = 0) AND (ccparent = 0))
               Rows Removed by Filter: 2
               Heap Blocks: exact=6291
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on transactions_user_id_key  (cost=0.00..73.29 rows=13601 width=0) (actual time=15.901..15.901 rows=12343 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (user_id = 1)
 Planning time: 0.895 ms
 Execution time: 1326.424 ms
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to speed up this query?  Like I said, it's the most run query in my application and is also one of the most demanding on the DB.  If I could optimize this, it would have tremendous benefits to the app in general.

Comment: I suspect that indices are all you'll need here, however, because of the nature of your query you have some options. You could calculate the sums for a historical set of records and store that value and then just calculate it for new data when it's requested, store the most recent id and the sums associated with it as the new historical value and then return. That way you only have to look back as far as their most recent lookup.

Comment: Also, your primary key syntax could use some work: `id bigserial primary key` will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Try if it picks up an index on `transactions (user_id, parent, ccparent, transaction_type, account_id, reconciled)`.

```
CREATE INDEX transactions_u_p_ccp_tt_a_r_idx
             ON transactions
                (user_id,
                 parent,
                 ccparent,
                 transaction_type,
                 account_id,
                 reconciled);
```

Maybe you can even include `amount` in the index.

```
CREATE INDEX transactions_u_p_ccp_tt_a_r_a_idx
             ON transactions
                (user_id,
                 parent,
                 ccparent,
                 transaction_type,
                 account_id,
                 reconciled,
                 amount);
```

Comment: I was worried that having such complex indexes might affect the performance of the table when it comes to other actions (insert, update).  Is that an unfair assumption?  Again, the table has about 30 million rows in it and is used extremely frequently.

Comment: @BrandonO: Of course it will have impact on the `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s (but for the latter indexes may also be a benefit, as one part of an `UPDATE` is the retrieval, that could be faster with an appropriate index). But I wouldn't worry that much about it. You'd have to try it. And then see what weighs more. I think it's likely that the decrease in speed of writes is neglectable but the increase in speed for your query is significant.

Comment: It's proving difficult to test since after running the query once, the query planner seems to better account for it and running the same query back to back will result in the second time being something like 78ms vs 5000ms.  I'll keep playing with this and see if some different indexes will help.